# Display information in dropdown list from database query PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, database-connection

I'm having trouble with a bit of code I wrote, I can't seem to find any problems with it and its driving me crazy

```
    // create connection
$conn=odbc_connect('SkyeGaccess1','','');

if (!$conn)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}

  $sql = "SELECT Username FROM Customers";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='Username'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Username'] ."'>" . $row['Username'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

I've looked around everywhere and this seems to be exactly how I'm supposed to write this piece of code. Its not a problem with the database connection as I can put the information into a table just fine, but I just can't get it to show up on the dropdown list.

Comment: Have you checked the rowcount to make sure anything's being returned?

Comment: First off, you're mixing `odbc_connect()` and `mysql_query()`, which is two different extensions. Secondly, you shouldn't use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. (They have been deprecated for a few years now). You should really consider using pdo instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Magnus, you're a life saver. Got everything working just fine now.

Comment: @SkyeG - That's what I do... saving lives on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code. This will help!

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('SkyeGaccess1','','');//altered
if (!$conn)
  {die("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}//altered

  $sql = "SELECT Username FROM Customers";
$rs = mysqli_query($sql);

echo "<select name='Username'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { //altered
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Username'] ."'>" . $row['Username'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Ping here on any issues!